# Как сделать div 100% по ширине на мобильном?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Условия: на страницах есть блоки разной ширины, заданные в пикселях.
Надо добавить еще один блок на 100% ширины.

Проблема:
Если к существующему блоку шириной, например, в `1000px`, добавить блок с `width = 100%`, то на устройствах с шириной экрана меньше `1000px`, браузер масштабируется так, чтобы блок `1000px` влез целиком. При этом блок с `width = 100%` получается шириной, равной физической ширине экрана.
Т.е. в цифрах - экран 412х732. Вот блок и получается шириной 412 пикселей, а не желаемые 1000. Визуально блок с `width = 100%` не на весь экран. А `1000px` — на весь.

Если блоку жестко задать 1000, то конечно все получится, но максимальная ширина блоков (и их количество) на странице не известна - она может быть разной.

В примере ниже два блока должны быть одной ширины.
Поменять всю существующую верстку под какой-либо правильно-кошерный вариант не получится, можно только добавить любой javascript и любой css для `div2`.

```css
.div1 {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div class="div1">width: 1000px</div>
    <div class="div2">width: 100%</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Скриншот того, что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте для `body` стиль `display: inline-block;`. Это будет работать, потому что inline-block позволяет элементу подстраиваться под величину контента:

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
}

.div1 {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: green;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">width: 1000px</div>
<div class="div2">width: 100%</div>
```

Comment: Магия... Непонятно как, но работает и не ломает существующую верстку.

Comment: @georgas Всё просто. `inline-block` позволяет элементу подстраиваться под величину контента.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло!

Comment: Пожалуйста, очень приятно это слышать.